# Method is undefined for a class

Tags: java, object, methods, undefined

I am trying to run a code in eclipse that uses a method called getArea(an object). I am currently getting an error saying

> The method `getArea(ComparableRectangle)` is undefined for the type `RectangleTest`

This is the code for RectangleTest-

```
package geometry;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class RectangleTest extends Rectangle {
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3282103336310735942L;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ComparableRectangle rect01 = new ComparableRectangle(5, 4);
        ComparableRectangle rect02 = new ComparableRectangle(6, 8);
        System.out.println("Area: " + getArea(rect01));

    }
 }
```

And this is the code for ComparableRectangle.

```
package geometry;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class ComparableRectangle extends Rectangle implements Comparable {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public ComparableRectangle(int w, int h) {
         width = w;
         height = h;
     }
     public double getArea(ComparableRectangle rect) {
         return width*height;
     }
     public boolean compareTo(ComparableRectangle rect1, ComparableRectangle rect2) {
         if(rect1.width == rect2.width && rect1.height == rect2.height) {
             return true;
          }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How do I clarify that rect01 is a ComparableRectangle?

Comment: You need something like `rect01.getArea(rect01)`. You have to call the method on an object which is of a type that has that method. You can see that the parameter you are passing in is not used and could be removed.

Comment: You code looks quite broken, sorry. `getArea(...)` takes a `ComparableRectangle` as a parameter and the completely ignores it. You could just drop the parameter. In the test simply call `rect01.getArea()`.

Comment: Why two `compareTo` methods? The first one is actually a `compare` and not `compareTo` method since it compares two given objects instead of the own instance **to** another.

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented language like `Java` or `C++` to call a class method you need a instance of that class, which we call also an `object` instantiated from that class. So you have to call your method like below:-

```
 rect02.getArea(rect01);
 rect01.getArea(rect02);
```

Because `getArea(ComparableRectangle rect)` is a member function or method of class `ComparableRectangle` hence you need its instance to call it. Here are two instances of that class rect01 and rect02.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood how methods and their parameters work.

You need some way to combine the method with some object it should be called on. Currently you do so by using the object as parameter, but this is not correct.

You should combine object and method by writing

```
obj.method();
```

Therefore, you should call the method like

```
rect01.getArea();
```

and remove the parameter from the method

```
public double getArea() { ... }
```

Parameters can be used to give the method additional information on the way. A good example is the `compareTo` method which is supposed to compare the current instance with the given instance. A call would look like

```
rect01.compareTo(rect02);
```

and the methods signature is

```
 public int compareTo(Object o)
```

Note that it only has one parameter as the current instance is implicitly known to the method (`this` keyword).

---

### Notes

There is no need for the additional custom `compareTo` method, which by the way should be named `compare` and should be `static` since it's not bound to any instance.

Also note that your custom `compareTo`method is **not comparing**. It just returns *same* or *not same*. But for an order you need *less than*, *greater than* and *equals*. Your method thus does not define an order.